# Derivative of a finite continued fraction

Tags: real-analysis, fractions, continued-fractions

> Let
>   $$f(x)=x-\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{....-\frac{1}{x-1}}}$$
>   where the fraction is iterated $2018$ times. I need to find $f'(0)$.

I'm a bit confused with this problem, I can't express it like that $f(x)=x-\frac{1}{f(x)}$ because the process is finite, how can I figure it out then?

Comment: By the way, there is no  function satisfying $f(x)=x-\frac{1}{f(x)}$. For $x=0$ we would get $f(0)^2 = -1$.

Comment: Is the answer = -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)$ be the function where the fraction is iterated $n-1$ times. Then $f_1(x)=x-1$ and for $n\geq 1$
$$f_{n+1}(x)=x-\frac{1}{f_n(x)}.$$
Then it is easy to verify that $f_n(0)=(-1)^n$. We show by induction that $f'_n(0)=n$.
It holds for $n=1$. For the inductive step, we have that
$$f'_{n+1}(x) =\frac{d}{dx}\left(x-\frac{1}{f_n(x)}\right)= 1 + \dfrac{f'_n(x)}{f_n(x)^2}$$
and for $x=0$ we find
$$f'_{n+1}(0) = 1 + \dfrac{n}{((-1)^n)^2}=n+1$$
and we are done.

Comment: Why is $f(x)=x-\frac{1}{f(x)}$?

Comment: no, it is not given in the question... :(

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you for your comment. I misread the question at first. Now it should be ok.

Comment: It is okay, but you can simplify it by observing that $f'_{n+1}(x) = 1 + \dfrac{f'_n(x)}{f_n(x)^2}$, thus $f'_{n+1}(0) = 1+ f'_n(0)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Is the answer 2020?

Comment: @PaulFront Good point! Thanks.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha I Think it is 2019 as in you answer because "iterated 2018 times" means that we consider $f_{2019}$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Ah, yes, I get same. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**

$$ f(x) := \left (x-\dfrac{1}{x- \dfrac{1}{x - \dots}}\right)_{2018} $$

Then,

$$ f'(x) = 1+\left ( \dfrac{1}{x - \dfrac{1}{\dots}}\right)^2_{2017}.\left (  
 1 + \left ( \dfrac 1 {x - \dfrac 1 \dots} \right)^2 \dots\right)_{2016} $$

Observe the square symbol ensures that the value inside the brackets to be positive, then

$$f'(0) = 1 + \underbrace{1^2.(1+1^2(1+1^2(1+1^2 \dots)))}_{\text{open 2018 brackets}}$$

Then, you'll get the answer 2018+1 = 2019$\blacksquare$